# react-bootstrap ModalTrigger doesn't work on React components

Tags: react-bootstrap

Looks like the ModalTrigger doesn't play well when being supplied a React component. Consider the following:

```
var MyDiv = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return <div>Click me!</div>
    }
});

var Content = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return <div>
                    <ModalTrigger modal={<MyModal/>}>
                        <MyDiv/>
                    </ModalTrigger>
                    <ModalTrigger modal={<MyModal/>}>
                        <div>No, click me!</div>
                    </ModalTrigger>
               </div>
    }
});

React.render(<Content/>, document.getElementById("mydiv"));
```

When clicking on the first div, nothing happens, but the second div opens the modal as expected.

The DOM looks identical, but when using the React extension for Chrome I can see that there is an additional React component between the first ModalTrigger and the underlying div, named `MyDiv`.

The reason this is a problem is that ModalTrigger depends on its child element `onClick` to show the modal. When using a regular div it works as expected, but since the direct child here is a React component, there is no obvious way to make this connection go to the actual div component.

So my question, is this a shortcoming of react-bootstrap that cannot deal with the way React instantiates components, or is this the normal / expected behavior that I should work around somehow?

Thanks!

Edit: 
I wanted to post this as a comment but could not format it properly :/

One way of getting around this is to have MyDiv aware that it has a `this.props.onClick` method, and trigger it explicitly:

```
var MyDiv = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return <div onClick={this.props.onClick>Click me!</div>
    }
});
```

This creates coupling (or extra lines for PropTypes/getDefaultProps to decouple), which is far from ideal.

Another way is to wrap MyDiv in another anonymous div:

```
<ModalTrigger modal={<MyModal/>}>
    <div><MyDiv/></div>
</ModalTrigger>
```

Which is much better, but somehow doesn't feel right either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer is under the MyDiv's responsibility, at least in how react-bootstrap works. The magic happens when the top-level `div` in `MyDiv` is passed the props, like so:

```
var MyDiv = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return <div {...this.props}>Click me!</div>
    }
});
```

This is both in step with react-bootstrap's inner components' behavior, and allows MyDiv to remain agnostic of whatever is passed through. It's probably better, as [Facebook](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html#rest-and-spread-properties-...) suggests, to use the harmony destructuring syntax (e.g., `var {myProp, ...otherProps} = this.props` and then using it in `<MyDiv {...otherProps}/>`), but, well... harmony.